# method in data access class not working because of wrong sql-statement (I think)

Tags: java, sql

I made a method in a data access class that needs to get data from multiple tables. I want to show a table on a webpage with this data.

I tried to use inner joins the get the different data and filled each class up underneath it. I think the problem is located in the sql-statement since the other code 'matches' previously used code that did work. The webpage and servlet should be fine as well.

````
          ArrayList<Vlucht> vluchtGegevens = new ArrayList<>();

         try (
             Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password);
             Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
             ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM vlucht "
                     + " inner join vliegtuig on vlucht.vliegtuig_id = vliegtuig.id "
                     + " inner join vliegtuigtype on vliegtuig.vliegtuigtype_id = vliegtuigtype.id "
                     + " inner join luchthaven as VL on vlucht.vertrekluchthaven_id = VL.id "
                     + " inner join luchthaven as AL on vlucht.aankomstluchthaven_id = AL.id");) 
            {
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                 Vlucht vlucht = new Vlucht();
                 vlucht.setId(resultSet.getInt(1));
                 vlucht.setCode(resultSet.getString("code"));
                 vlucht.setVertrekTijd(resultSet.getDate("vertrekTijd"));
                 vlucht.setAankomstTijd(resultSet.getDate("aankomstTijd"));
                 vlucht.setVliegtuig_id(resultSet.getInt("vliegtuig_id"));
                 vlucht.setVertrekluchthaven_id(resultSet.getInt("vertrekluchthaven_id"));
                 vlucht.setAankomstluchthaven_id(resultSet.getInt("aankomstluchthaven_id"));

                 Vliegtuig vliegtuig = new Vliegtuig();
                 vliegtuig.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
                 vliegtuig.setVliegtuigType_id(resultSet.getInt("vliegtuigtype_id"));
                 vliegtuig.setLuchtvaartMaatschappij_id(resultSet.getInt("luchtvaartMaatschappij_id"));
                 vlucht.setVliegtuig(vliegtuig);

                 VliegtuigType vliegtuigType = new VliegtuigType();
                 vliegtuigType.setId(resultSet.getInt(5));
                 vliegtuigType.setTypenaam(resultSet.getString("typenaam"));

                 vlucht.setVliegtuigType(vliegtuigType);

                 Luchthaven vertrekLuchthaven = new Luchthaven();
                 vertrekLuchthaven.setId(resultSet.getInt(6));
                 vertrekLuchthaven.setLuchthavennaam(resultSet.getString("luchthavennaam"));
                 vertrekLuchthaven.setStad(resultSet.getString("stad"));
                 vertrekLuchthaven.setLand_id(resultSet.getInt("land_id"));

                 vlucht.setVertrekLuchthaven(vertrekLuchthaven);

                 Luchthaven aankomstLuchthaven = new Luchthaven();
                 aankomstLuchthaven.setId(resultSet.getInt(7));
                 aankomstLuchthaven.setLuchthavennaam(resultSet.getString("luchthavennaam"));
                 aankomstLuchthaven.setStad(resultSet.getString("stad"));
                 aankomstLuchthaven.setLand_id(resultSet.getInt("land_id"));

                 vlucht.setAankomstLuchthaven(aankomstLuchthaven);
                 vluchtGegevens.add(vlucht);


                            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         return vluchtGegevens  ;
    }
    ```
````

Comment: did you try to debug this query using some IDE tool? Are you sure that columns "vertrekTijd", "vliegtuigtype_id" etc present in resultset? miss of any will result an exception leading to empty result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example are great introductions when asking the first questions here.

Comment: But what is the problem here? What is not working (I assume something isn't)? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: No, I don't get any error, just an empty table on the web-page, meaning that there is (probably) a mistake in my sql-statement

Comment: Did you try debugging your code? Check if there are any results and such?

Comment: Did you try running your sql directly against the db using some sql client tool?

Comment: Amongalen, I ran the project with a breakpoint on the line where it should return the ArrayList. The arraylist it is returning is empty.

Comment: How can you create 2 Luchthaven objects when they get their values from the same column? All flights will depart and arrive at the same airport! I don't think you can do 'SELECT *' like this, you need to write out each column individually in the SELECT and use alias for those that appears twice so you can tell them apart.

Comment: I've added the columns to the select, added round hooks around the inner joins and changed column names with multiple occurances to their matching numbers (the ones I used for the id's in post were wrong), but I still get an empty arraylist after running the code. I looked into the db and have data that should match the sql-statement...

Answer (score 0):

The word 'as' had to be removed from the sql-statement. This caused a problem because I was using Netbeans.